# how to equate length of two column and display it as null

Tags: sql, database

6)Write a query to display the f_name , l_name , length of f_name,  length of l_name for all employees . if length of f_name is equal to  length of l_name display null if length of f_name is not equal to  length of l_name display length of f_name.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: like java if else statement , here i wants to display null if two column have equal number of characters in each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NULLIF()` for this specific case. For example:

```
select
  f_name, l_name, length(f_name), length(l_name),
  nullif(length(f_name), length(l_name))
from employee
```

Result:

```
 f_name   l_name  length  length  nullif 
 -------- ------- ------- ------- ------ 
 Patrick  Smith   7       5       7      
 Anna     Leon    4       4       null
```

For more more generic conditions you can use a `CASE` statement to evaluate an expression and produce different outputs depending on it.

For example:

```
select
  f_name, l_name, length(f_name), length(l_name),
  case when length(f_name) = length(l_name) then null else length(f_name)
  end
from employee
```

Result:

```
 f_name   l_name  length  length  length 
 -------- ------- ------- ------- ------ 
 Patrick  Smith   7       5       7      
 Anna     Leon    4       4       null
```

See both examples running at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jX6qAan2Y82vTWovqaAxdf/0).